# CakePHP doesn't see multiple relations HABTM while SQL query works fine

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-model

Cake query:

```
$this->Token->find("first", array(
    "conditions" => array(
             "Token.token" => $token),
    "contain" => array( 
             "TokenGroup" => array(
                          "TokenPermission" => array("fields" => array("path") )
) ) ));
```

Returns (in part) something like this:

```
[TokenGroup] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => admin
        [modified] => 2013-03-07 00:00:00
        [created] => 2013-03-07 00:00:00
        [TokenPermission] => Array
            (
            )

    )
```

TokenPermition array is empty, but when I use SQL:

```
SELECT 
   TokenPermission.path 
FROM 
    tokens AS Token 
INNER JOIN 
   token_groups AS TokenGroup ON (Token.token_group_id = TokenGroup.id) 
INNER JOIN 
   token_groups_token_permissions AS JoinTable ON (TokenGroup.id = JoinTable.token_group_id) 
INNER JOIN 
   token_permissions AS TokenPermission ON (TokenPermission.id = JoinTable.token_permission_id); 
WHERE 
   Token.token = $token
```

It returns me TokenPermission data:

```
[TokenPermission] => Array
      (
             [path] => TOKEN_NUMBER
      )
```

Also when I tied ask for different user group permissions It can returnes permission assigned for group number 1 - which is not user but admin!

**So why Cake doesn't see correct relations if SQL returns everything fine?**

Answer (score 0):

You may find the answer if look at queries run by Cake. Put the code after find method:

```
$this->Token->->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me. With this code or without, results are the same. Which doesn't mean that results are always empty. It returns me something, but for example permissions refer to admin while they shoud be related to regular user.